# Change angle of Div to greater than 90 degrees and keep css Hover effect

Tags: html, css

I have the below code, which creates a 90 degree downwards pointing triangle using CSS only. I've also added a hover effect to it, so that when someone hovers over it, the opacity changes from 0.7 to 1.

What I am wondering... Is is possible to increase the angle of the downwards pointing angle, and still keep the hover effect? I've found an example that allows me to create a 'Chevron' shape using the :before and :after elments of a div. But this then causes some issues with the hover effect. Can you use pure CSS to style ONE element to look like a downwards pointing arrow, greater than 90 degrees?

Any help appreciated :)

HTML:

```
<div id="linkHolder">
    <a id="more" title="More information about Dabble" href="#">
            <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#linkHolder {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
#more {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 80px; 
    height: 80px; 
    border-right: 10px solid rgba(37, 198, 94, 0.7);
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(37, 198, 94, 0.7);
    margin: auto;
    padding:0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    transition: 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: ease 1s;
    -o-transition: ease 1s;
    z-index:10;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.arrow-down:hover,
.arrow-down:focus {
    border-right: 10px solid rgba(37, 198, 94, 1);
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(37, 198, 94, 1);
}
```